# Can someone help me with solving a second orden differential,with initial condition?(Simple oscillator)

Tags: python, sympy, physics

I'm new to this community,and I was searching for help, but couldn't find it so I'm doing the question.
I'm doing a homework about the use of sympy on python and could advance writing the equation and solving it for general solutions. Here my code:

```
import sympy as sym
t=sym.symbols('t') #time
x=sym.Function('x')(t) #position
m=sym.symbols('m') #mass
k=sym.symbols('k')#const. 0<k
ac=x.diff(t,t)#acceleration
eos=sym.Eq(m*ac, -k*x)#equation
ecres=sym.dsolve(eos,x)#the general solution
```

This works fine,giving me a C1 and a C2. But now I'm trying to get the solution for initial condition.

```
x0=sym.symbols('x0')#initial condition for position
v0=sym.symbols('v0')#initial condition for velocity
vel=x.diff(t)#velocity
ics={t:0,x:x0,vel:v0}
ayuda=[[t,0],[x,x0],[vel,v0]]
```

I tried with

```
ecres.evalf(subs={ics})
ecres.evalf(subs={ayuda})
```

Finally with

```
ecres.subs(t,0).subs(x,x0).subs(vel,v0)
```

But still couldn't change the C1 and C2 for the solution.
¿What command do I need to change them?
Thank you very much for the help.

Ps:Sorry if it was kind of long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass the ics when calling `dsolve`. There is a particular format for specifying the ics:

```
In [48]: t, m, k, x0, v0 = symbols('t, m, k, x0, v0')

In [49]: x = Function('x')(t)

In [50]: ac = x.diff(t, t)

In [51]: eos = Eq(m*ac, -k*x)

In [52]: dsolve(eos, x)
Out[52]: 
                  _____             _____
                 ╱ -k              ╱ -k  
           -t⋅  ╱  ───        t⋅  ╱  ─── 
              ╲╱    m           ╲╱    m  
x(t) = C₁⋅ℯ             + C₂⋅ℯ           


In [54]: dsolve(eos, x, ics={x.subs(t, 0):x0, x.diff(t).subs(t, 0):v0})
Out[54]: 
                                    _____                              _____
                                   ╱ -k                               ╱ -k  
       ⎛             _____⎞  -t⋅  ╱  ───    ⎛            _____⎞  t⋅  ╱  ─── 
       ⎜            ╱ -k  ⎟     ╲╱    m     ⎜           ╱ -k  ⎟    ╲╱    m  
       ⎜-v₀ + x₀⋅  ╱  ─── ⎟⋅ℯ               ⎜v₀ + x₀⋅  ╱  ─── ⎟⋅ℯ           
       ⎝         ╲╱    m  ⎠                 ⎝        ╲╱    m  ⎠             
x(t) = ────────────────────────────────── + ────────────────────────────────
                        _____                               _____           
                       ╱ -k                                ╱ -k             
                  2⋅  ╱  ───                          2⋅  ╱  ───            
                    ╲╱    m                             ╲╱    m
```